# setting the width of one element same as other using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

Why doesn't this code make the width of the search bar same as the header?

```js
@model SearchModel
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let width = document.getElementById('header').offsetWidth();
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--width', width);
    </script>
}

<head>
    <style>
        :root{
            --width: 0px;
        }
        #search-bar{
            width: var(--width);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="get">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="search-bar" asp-for="@Model.SearchString" value="@Model.SearchString" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I even tried using:

```js
@model SearchModel
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let width = document.getElementById('header').offsetWidth();
        document.getElementById('search-bar').style.setProperty('width', width);
    </script>
}

<body>
    <form method="get">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="search-bar" asp-for="@Model.SearchString" value="@Model.SearchString" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

But to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I found you use getElementById to get the header width. Does your application contains the element which has ID named header ? If this is no element which ID is header, you couldn't get the right width.

Besides, normally, the header's width is the browser's width by default. If header element doesn't set the value, I suggest you could try to use below workaround to get the bower width and set it.

More details, you could refer to below  codes:

```
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getWidth() {
            return Math.max(
                document.body.scrollWidth,
                document.documentElement.scrollWidth,
                document.body.offsetWidth,
                document.documentElement.offsetWidth,
                document.documentElement.clientWidth
            );
        }
            alert(getWidth());
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--width', getWidth());
    </script>
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have `id`ed my header as `header`

Comment: Could you please share your html makeup?

Comment: html markup https://gist.github.com/kesarling/41fa88110a90ec872339738d90eb67c0